# Varnish Disrupting Logins with Invision Power Board

Tags: nginx, varnish

I recently transferred one of my primary sites over to a WordPress installation, but unfortunately, this resulted in extremely high server loads. Originally, I was running a basic LAMP server with several sites. The one I'm primarily concerned with right now is a site that gets around 60,000 hits a day and has a very active forum which uses Invision Power Board.

That brings me to where I am now. I swapped out apache for nginx, optimized MySQL a little, and installed Varnish. This has helped a lot and works with everything except my Invision Power Board installation. For whatever the reason, IPB will no longer let me log in or out. On one of my computers that I was logged in on, I'm able to stay logged in. But if I try to log into the ACP or into the forums from another computer or browser, it will not work. Below are my settings in Varnish:

```
sub vcl_recv {
   if (req.http.host ~ "^(www\.)?domain1\.net$") {
       set req.http.host = "domain1.net";
       set req.backend = domain1;
       return (lookup);
   }
   if (req.http.host == "old.domain1.net") {
       #You will need the following line only if your backend has multiple virtual host names
       set req.http.host = "old.domain1.net";
       set req.backend = olddomain1;
       return (lookup);
   }
   if (req.http.host ~ "^(www\.)?domain2\.net$") {
       set req.http.host = "domain2.net";
       set req.backend = domain2;
       return (lookup);
   }
   if (req.http.host ~ "^(www\.)?domain3\.com$") {
       set req.http.host = "domain3.com";
       set req.backend = domain3;
       return (lookup);
   }
   if (req.http.host ~ "^(www\.)?domain4\.org$") {
       set req.http.host = "domain4.org";
       set req.backend = domain4;
       return (lookup);
   }
}


# Drop any cookies sent to Wordpress.
sub vcl_recv {
    #exclusion for one domain that has low-views and maybe have unexpected results
    if (!(req.http.host ~ "^(www\.)?domain4\.org$")) {
        if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
            if (!(req.url ~ "forums")) {
                    unset req.http.cookie;
            }
        }
    }
}

# Drop any cookies Wordpress tries to send back to the client.
sub vcl_fetch {
    #exclusion for one domain that has low-views and maybe have unexpected results
    if (!(req.http.host ~ "^(www\.)?domain4\.org$")) {
            if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
                if (!(req.url ~ "forums")) {
                        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I'm very new to nginx and varnish. I saw one other question asked for this, but no good solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing explicit `return(lookup)` in your first vcl_recv.  This means that the code in the second vcl_recv block will only ever be run if the request doesn't hit any of the conditions in the first block (i.e., if it's not `^(((www\.|old\.)?domain1\.net)|((www\.)?domain(2\.net|3\.com|4\.org))$`) *and* all the other parts of the second vcl_recv `if` blocks succeed.

Fundamentally, you're overriding Varnish's perfectly good builtin logic here, which would have passed the requests for the logged-in users (that is, the ones with cookies) to the backend, while serving the rest out of cache, if available.  You could get the result you're looking for simply by removing all the `return(lookup)`s.  But if you're insistent on doing it the current way, you just need to add:

```
sub vcl_hash {
  if ( req.http.Cookie ) {
    hash_data( req.http.Cookie );
  }
}
```

The advantage to overriding Varnish's logic is that even cookies that have no bearing whatsoever on the server's handling of the request, like Google Analytics urchin IDs, will cause every request to hit the backend.  To avoid this, either whitelist the cookies that the server cares about, or blacklist those that it won't; a number of techniques to accomplish this are available around the Web and at https://www.varnish-cache.org/ .

Edit: Expanding slightly, what's happening here is that you're telling Varnish that, if a request comes in for, let's say, domain1, then to use domain1's backend, and then to try to retrieve that object from cache.  If it's not present in cache, it will fetch it from the backend and store it in cache.  So long as there's no Set-Cookie header present in the response (which, in default.vcl, causes the object to be uncacheable), the next time someone asks for that same page, they'll see it as whichever user (or whichever "non-user", in the case of someone who isn't logged in) saw it last, presuming that the TTL hasn't expired.  What we do with the `vcl_hash` code is say to Varnish that it should consider cached objects different based on the Cookie that was delivered with the request.  We could easily improve this--for example, we could only care about the cookie for pages that don't end in `\.(jpg|png|gif|AndSoForth)$`, but the right place to do that is in `vcl_recv`, where we should simply strip the Cookie header altogether for such requests.

Comment: Like I said, I'm completely new to this, so I'm not actually sure what return(lookup) does. I mean, I understand what a programmatic return does in programming languages, but in the context of Varnish, I'm not sure.

I was using those because I have multiple domains. I'll try your suggestion of removing them in the shortrun, but I'll definitely look into whitelisting specific cookies.

Answer (score 0):

First - you have two `vcl_recv` functions, you need to combine those into one.

But that's just related to blocking cookies sent to the server; seems like sending cookies to the client is where your problem is if an existing session stays working.

Do a test login without Varnish; when's the `Set-Cookie` being sent by the server?  Find where that happens, then test with Varnish again and see if that `Set-Cookie` is being sent properly in that case.  It might just be that the `if (!(req.url ~ "forums")) {` exemption isn't catching for the resource that sends the cookie.